# How do I change the design of an already existing ship or base?

Tags: distant-worlds-legends

I've edited the default designs for my mining stations to include a little more firepower, however I'm not sure how to get the mining stations I've already built to switch over to the new design.

How do I change the design of an already existing ship or base?

Comment: If you click (focus) on the station, is there not a "Retrofit" button at the bottom of the context window?

Comment: @mxmissile It's been a while since I've played, but I don't recall that doing anything. It's possible I just had to wait for a construction ship to get there, and they were too busy doing other things.,